# How do I upload a picture on here?

Tags: discussion, graphics

I need to know how to upload a photo on here (on this website only) from my iPod Touch (4th gen.) when I ask another question. It's from the photo library on my iPod. I want to include it with my question to show others what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help protect the site from spam, new users are not allowed to post pictures in their posts. Once you ask or answer questions and earn ten reputation points, [the new user restrictions are lifted](https://apple.stackexchange.com/privileges/new-user). The more reputation points a person earns, the more [privileges](https://apple.stackexchange.com/privileges/) a user unlocks on the site.

If your question needs an image to work, you can upload the image to a site like [imgur.com](http://imgur.com) and include the link in your question, and a user with more reputation can edit your post to include the image inline.